# YAML language renamed to docker-compose in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Been using vscode for a while, mainly on a remote server to work on docker-compose.yml
I've installed a bunch of extensions, including YAML (by Red Hat), Docker, Docker Compose, Docker Language Basics, etc..

A few days ago I noticed that the YAML language "doesn't exist", but rather the entire Yaml language is now called "docker-compose (yaml) - configured language"

I've tried disabling the relevant extensions; Searching the Settings; Googling it; ChatGPT/Bard it. Can't find a solution to revert it or where it is set.

How do I rename it back?

Comment: Try executing `Start Extension Bisect` and see if some extension causes that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, @Dimava's answer was the solution. Running `Start Extension Bisect` discovered an unrelated extension that was breaking it